# Boot/ScreenOn Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have a blank HelloWorld Application:

```
package tutorials.TestReceivers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestReceiversActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

With this BootReceiver.Java:

```
package tutorials.TestReceivers;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestReceiversActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);    
    }
}
```

and this manifest:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TestReceiversActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android-permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:name="development.TestReceiversActivity.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

After running the application and closing it.

When I unlock screen (SCREEN_ON) nothing happend.

And when i boot the decive I'm getting next msg like:

"The application TestReceiversActivity (tutorials.TestReceivers process) stop unexpectedly. Try again"

Comment: SCREEN_ON not working from manifest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a long time of frustration, I solved the problem above.

The right way to register Boot Broadcast Receiver (and open activity according to it), is:

Blank HelloWorld Application (TestReceiversActivity.java):

```
package tutorials.TestReceivers;

import android.app.Activity;
public class TestReceiversActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Another Boot Receiver Class (BootReceiver.java)

```
package tutorials.TestReceivers;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.d("DAVID", "Hi, Boot reciver was catch!");
         Intent i = new Intent(context, TestReceiversActivity.class);
         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(i);
       }
}
```

Note: You must set the flag to make it work!

Set the manifest to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="tutorials.TestReceivers"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".TestReceiversActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 </manifest>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Delete `android-permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`. Add a `<uses-permission>` element for this permission as a child of the `<manifest>` element.

If the problems continue, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot) showing how to get control at boot time.

`SCREEN_ON` will not work from the manifest.