# Register / Unregister boot broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I registered a boot broadcast receiver according to this post:

[Launch activity using boot broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115687/boot-screenon-broadcast-receiver-not-working/8264035#8264035)

And I'm wondering how to unregister it? / can it register/unregister programmatically?

The problem is that the register was done in the manifest and not programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you register a BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest, it will be triggered even if the app is not running. If you register a BroadcastReceiver in an Activity, then it will be triggered only when the code is running and it should be unregistered when the acitivty is inactive.

Since this is a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast, registering in the codes doesn't make sense. It should be registered in the Manifest, and I don't think we can unregister it. However, we can ignore it by checking some boolean variables from the SharedPreferences or a file inside the `onReceive()` method, etc. Like:

```
if(condition){//use the variables to verify the condition
//do something
}
```