# Android-Launching an application when tablet boot up is completed

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent

i am using Android 3.2, i created my android application and that will start automatically when my tablet start booting is completed.

Everything works fine except the activity is running **twice** when apps is start running automatically *(after boot completed)*.

This problem is not raised when i start the app manually.

public class BootStartUpApp extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startUpApps = new Intent(context, StartMainActivity.class);
    startUpApps.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(startUpApps);
}
```

}

in Manifest file i added below code :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="com.logica.eHealthBox.tab.activity.BootStartUpApp" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Having any code to show us?.. The BroadcastReceiver part would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do it:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Intent i = new Intent(context, TestReceiversActivity.class);
         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(i);
       }
}
```

put an entry in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" />
```

and have the activity too.

for more info , check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8264035/878126) and [this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Comment: same code is used that in post,its working fine,But my question is activity is Running Twice when apps is launched after  booting is completed